# How to implement a delete folders step in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

In TeamCity 8.1 I've just pulled down my source code and the first thing I want to do is delete a bunch of subfolders from what I've just retrieved.

I can't use exclusions in the 'Checkout Rules' so I guess I need a separate step to run immediately after retrieving source code.

I guess I need a CommandLine Step? If so I can't seem to find much information about using this to delete a number of sub folders?

[image]

Anyone with experience in this area?

Comment: Does it have to be in a .cmd file?

Comment: Well unless anyone has any bright ideas i'll write a powershell script and use the powershell command runner

Comment: Just curious why can't you use checkout rules to exclude folders.

Comment: Nadeem, they don't seem to actually exclude subfolders if I have explicitly mapped a parent folder

Comment: I've decided to use the checkout rules to exclude the folders it just means I can't do folder mapping.. :-(

Comment: You can also use an Ant build step and provide custom build.xml content using Web UI.

But the good way is to use checkout rules. Could you pleases give more details on your troubles with them?

Answer (score 1):

In our team city setup we wanted to delete all existing files in working directory.

We have first build step which cleans up working directory contents using custom command line script.

```
del /s /q .
for /d %%%y in (.\*) do @rd /s /q "%%%y"
```

**Note:** We don't have VCS attached in this build configuration. If you have VCS attached then this solution won't work because TC will first download/copy contents from VCS then this build step will delete all the contents downloaded from VCS.

[image: TeamCity snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

1. use a command line to delete the folders using windows/unix commands. Teamcity publishes a property called  teamcity.build.checkoutDir using which you can go the directory and run the necessary delete commands(based on the OS where you are checking out).
2. A better way of doing this would be to add a target in your build.xml and call the target as the first step of your build